# Objective C - How to concatenate an entire array of strings?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am an Objective C newbie. I want to write a method that takes in an array of strings and returns a concatenated string, with a comma (,) in between each string. 
So if an array is {a b c d}, I want to return a,b,c,d.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I already knew this method but couldn't remember its name. Thanks to your question, `google` helped me to find it back.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, the simplest being

```
[yourArray componentsJoinedByString: @","]
```

Answer (score 17):

Use NSArray's `componentsJoinedByString:` method.

```
NSArray *strings = ...;
NSString *combined = [strings componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```